# What would be the best way to index a 2D tensor row-wise with keras backend?

Tags: python, keras

I have a tensor sized (n,) of integers and a 2D tensor sized=(n,k). For each "row" with index i in the 2D tensor I want to index it with the number in index i of the 1D tensor.

The idea would be to do it with Keras backend functions only as I'm running it on a GPU.

With a list compreension I would do it like this:

```
array = [1,2,0,0]
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,3,1],[3,2,1]])
print([matrix[i, num] for i, num in enumerate(array)])
```

Comment: I don't have tensorflow installed in my python env and can't install it since I use python 3.7, but looking at the docs this should be straightforward: `import tensorflow as tf`, `tf.gather_nd(matrix, [np.arange(array.size), array])`

Comment: Without tensorflow though. I wanted to use keras backend library. It also happens that tensorflow is not the backend I use.

Comment: And numpy? Is numpy ok?

Comment: As I'm running it on a GPU it wouldn't be very helpful. If there's no way to do it with keras backend I'll just use the backend specific library.